# Compilation failing when trying to run in API 16

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, retrolambda

I'm doing an app with RxJava2, Retrofit2, Retrolambda, etc. I have running the app well in the emulator with the latest SDK Nougat, but now I need to test on API 16, but I'm getting the next error. I'm going crazy with this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/Generated.class
```

I don't know how to debug this error.

build.gradle of project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://maven.batch.com/release" }
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: Try changing your project to eagerly fail when two libraries conflict. This will tell you who the culprit is. `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { failOnVersionConflict() } }`

Comment: Error:A conflict was found between the following modules:
 - com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
 - com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
 - com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4

Later it doesn't fail

Comment: And I only have gson 2.8 :S

Comment: Seems like that might be the problem, because one of your libraries may already have a version of it.

Comment: How I can resolve this? I've downgrade to 2.7 and now the problem is OkHttp, and next RxJava :S. With API 25 there is no problem!!! :SS